# from Flac to wav

Tags: audio, conversion, wav, flac, spectrogram

i have some flac files, some are from the same song but have a different size,
usually the larger size corresponds to a lower compression, to determine which is the best file I then go to see 2 other things:
the data stream, I am talking about audio cd, so 16bit with 44.1khz, and the data stream Kb / s should be 1.411 (for maximum quality)
also I go to see the spectrogram.
What I ask myself is:
if I convert the Flac file back to wav, and I don't know what kind of compression was used, if I understand correctly you can choose from 1 to 12,
so I find myself the flac file and I don't know how much compression has been applied, at the moment that I want to convert it back to wav the program recognizes how much compression was applied?
I believe that if the file is the result of a level 12 compression at the time of decompression the program should apply a factor of 12 etc. etc.
Or I'm wrong.
Please tell me what I need to do to restore and get the highest quality.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

FLAC is [lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAC) compression. During compression, you can set a compression option: setting this to a higher level creates a smaller file that is still lossless by taking more time to process the file. This compression level is included in the file, so the decoder will know how to decompress it.

So two FLACs created from the same source using different compression settings will have the same quality. There's no need to choose the larger file.